# Buildbot installation requires msvc14

Tags: buildbot, msvc14

I've been trying the [BuildBot *First Run* tutorial](https://docs.buildbot.net/current/tutorial/firstrun.html). It starts by creating a master and looks quite simple and straightforward, but I've encountered problems with the step `pip install 'buildbot[bundle]'`.

I get this error message (this is the end of the log):

```
building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\remi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Remi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-10x0qptg\\Twisted\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Remi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-c63k2sci\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Remi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-10x0qptg\Twisted\
```

I've tried installing mscv build tools, but still get the same message.

Any ideas how I could fix the problem?

Comment: Also be aware that there are 32-bit and 64-bit versions.

Comment: "MSVC**14**" is [the download for Visual Studio 20**15**](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?pid=2082).

Comment: Make sure you're installing the right tools to compile python packages, and that you restart after the installation. It is required because the package you're trying to install needs to be compiled. https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: I did install it, still got teh same error

Answer (score 0):

Problem is twisted does not yet support python 3.7 (see related issue here: [Installing Twisted for Python using pip: error: Microsoft Visual Studio failed with exit status 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51830649/installing-twisted-for-python-using-pip-error-microsoft-visual-studio-failed-w)).

You can work around this problem by installing precompiled twisted binaries. For example from here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted

E.g. in your case download Twisted‑18.9.0‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl and do

```
pip install Twisted‑18.9.0‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl
```

Then retry the buildbot install.

```
pip install 'buildbot[bundle]'
```